# Xen domU not resizing disk

Tags: partition, lvm, xen

My Xen server is using LVM for the domUs.  I shutdown a domU and increased its lv from 10G to 24G:

```
lvextend -L24G /dev/xen-disks/my_domu
```

which appears to have worked:

```
      --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/xen-disks/my_domu
  LV Name                my_domu
  VG Name                xen-disks
  LV UUID                EVe9Va-v1ls-FSVR-OlFZ-5juy-PkJ1-7MxDkZ
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time fractal, 2015-04-01 13:25:05 -0700
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                24.00 GiB
  Current LE             6144
  Segments               2
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     4096
  Block device           252:6
```

I can see the extra space inside the domU, but my attempts to increase the size of `/dev/xvda1` to make use of it have failed.

The domU's partition info from inside:

```
Disk /dev/xvda: 25.8 GB, 25769803776 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3133 cylinders, total 50331648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000e84db

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/xvda1              63    18860309     9430123+  83  Linux
/dev/xvda2        18860310    20964824     1052257+   5  Extended
/dev/xvda5        18860373    20964824     1052226   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

and its mount info:

```
/dev/xvda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
```

Any ideas on being able to use that 14 GB?

Comment: I have the same problem here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/560191/resize-a-xen-virtual-disk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domU has the larger size allocated, but internally it still only has the old size, see [Why do I need to do resize2fs after lvextend?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416886/why-do-i-need-to-do-resize2fs-after-lvextend).

You have to resize the filesystem with

```
resize2fs /dev/xen-disks/my_domu
```

(Eventually you have to call `e2fsck -f /dev/xen-disks/my_domu` beforehand)