# Why do I need to do resize2fs after lvextend?

Tags: partition, resize2fs

For resizing LVM2 partition, one needs to perform the following 2 commands:

```
# lvextend -L+1G /dev/myvg/homevol
# resize2fs /dev/myvg/homevol
```

However, when I perform `lvextend`, I see that the changes are already applied to the partition (as shown in Gnome Disks).  So why do I still need to do `resize2fs`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The `lvextend` command (without the `--resizefs` option) only makes the LVM-side arrangements to enlarge the block device that is the logical volume. No matter what the filesystem type (or even whether or not there is a filesystem at all) on the LV, these operations are always similar.

If the LV contains an ext2/3/4 filesystem, the next step is to update the filesystem metadata to make the filesystem aware that it has the more space available, and to create/extend the necessary metadata structures to manage the added space. In the case of ext2/3/4 filesystems, this involves at least:

- creating new inodes to the added space
- extending the block allocation data structures so that the filesystem can tell whether any block of the added space is in use or free
- potentially moving some data blocks around if they are in the way of the previously-mentioned data structure extension

This part is specific to the filesystem type, although the ext2/3/4 filesystem types are similar enough that they can all be resized with a single `resize2fs` tool. For XFS, filesystems, you would use a `xfs_growfs` tool instead. Other filesystems may have their own extension tools. And if the logical volume did not contain a filesystem but instead something like a "raw" database or an Oracle ASM volume, a yet another procedure would need to be applied.

Each filesystem has different internal workings and so the conditions for extending a filesystem will be different for each. It took a while until a common API was designed for filesystem extension; that made it possible to implement the `fsadm resize` command, which provides an unified syntax for extending several filesystem types. The `--resizefs` option of `lvextend` just uses the `fsadm resize` command.

In a nutshell: After `lvextend`, LVM-level tools such as `lvs`, `vgs`, `lvdisplay` and `vgdisplay` will see the updated size, but the filesystem and any tools operating on it, like `df`, won't see it yet.

Comment: Would it be right to say that after running `lvextend` and prior to running `resize2fs`, `df` would NOT report the updated sizes?

Comment: Exactly. (Added to my answer.)

Comment: Thanks. What does "creating new inodes to the added space" mean, given that  the added space is unused yet, and inodes exist for existing files only?

Comment: For modern filesystems like XFS it is so. However, the ext2/3/4 filesystems follow a more classic design, with a pre-allocated table of inodes. At filesystem creation time, a ratio of (maximum number of inodes) / (filesystem size) is set, and that cannot be changed as an on-line operation. As a result, the `resize2fs` needs to extend the inode table to maintain the ratio as the filesystem is extended.

Answer (score 15):

The LVM layer is just a container for the filesystem within.  You can tell `lvextend` to resize the filesystem within the logical volume without having to run a separate `resize2fs` adding the `-r` (or `--resizefs`) option:

```
lvextend -r ...
```

Comment: I was searching that option, beaten by seconds. +1

Answer (score 6):

Because filesystems and logical volumes are different abstractions. A volume is a chunk of disk (like a partition) — or at least, the "virtual" equivalent. It's just a block device. A filesystem is a structure that goes inside of that (or, on top of it, if you prefer) and which is used to provide a mapping between files (and directories and so on) to that device. Without `resize2fs`, the partition is bigger, but the filesystem isn't taking advantage of the available space.

You can actually create a filesystem *initially* which does not take up the entire partition. From the `mke2fs` man page:

> The file system size is specified by fs-size.  If fs-size does not have
>   a  suffix,  it  is interpreted as power-of-two kilobytes, unless the -b
>   blocksize option is specified, in which case fs-size is interpreted  as
>   the  number  of  blocksize blocks.   If the fs-size is suffixed by 'k',
>   'm', 'g', 't' (either upper-case or lower-case), then it is interpreted
>   in  power-of-two  kilobytes,  megabytes, gigabytes, terabytes, etc.  If
>   fs-size is omitted, mke2fs will create the file  system  based  on  the
>   device size.

As you can see, the default is to fill the partition, and there's usually no reason to do otherwise — but you can if you want.

Note that when `lvextend` has an option `--resizefs` (or just `-r`) which takes care of growing the filesystem after the volume has been extended without needing to run a separate command.

Answer (score 1):

The `resize2fs` forces the `fs`, filesystem to expand or shrink to take up the new space produced by the `lvextend` command.
The processes:

```
with fs:
        -- shrink --> 1. shrink fs 2. shrink volume
        -- expand --> 1. expand volume, 2. expand fs
```