# resize a xen virtual disk

Tags: lvm, xen

I have a VM running on my XEN host which goes low on diskspace. It has mounted its volume as `/dev/xvda2` formatted with a ext4 filesystem.

This is my xen config for the VM:

```
# /etc/xen/vm04.experimental.cfg

kernel      = '/boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-11-amd64'
extra       = 'elevator=noop'
ramdisk     = '/boot/initrd.img-4.9.0-11-amd64'
root        = '/dev/xvda2 ro'
disk        = [
                  'phy:/dev/vg0/vm04.experimental-disk,xvda2,w',
                  'phy:/dev/vg0/vm04.experimental-swap,xvda1,w',
              ]
...

# lvdisplay /dev/vg0/vm04.experimental-disk
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg0/vm04.experimental-disk
  LV Name                vm04.experimental-disk
  VG Name                vg0
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                60,00 GiB
  Current LE             15360
  Segments               5
  Allocation             inherit
...
```

there is still 44GB space left on my volumegroup `vg0`:

```
# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg0
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        2
  Metadata Sequence No  36766
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                27
  Open LV               22
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                2
  Act PV                2
  VG Size               1,07 TiB
  PE Size               4,00 MiB
  Total PE              281534
  Alloc PE / Size       270080 / 1,03 TiB
  Free  PE / Size       11454 / 44,74 GiB
```

How do I allocate the remaining space to my vm04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. shutdown the volume with:

   ```
   xen shutdown vm04.experimental
   ```
2. delete all snapshots of the volume:

   ```
   lvchange -an /dev/vg0/snap-tmp-vm04.experimental-disk    
   lvremove /dev/vg0/snap-tmp-vm04.experimental-disk
   ```
3. resize the volume, for example extend 40GB with:

   ```
   lvextend -L +40G /dev/vg0/vm04.experimental-disk
   ```

   Now the VM has the larger size of 100GB allocated, but internally it still only has 60GB disk
4. resize the filesystem

   ```
   resize2fs /dev/vg0/vm04.experimental-disk
   ```

   see [Why do I need to do resize2fs after lvextend?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416886/why-do-i-need-to-do-resize2fs-after-lvextend)
   (Eventually you have to call `e2fsck -f /dev/vg0/vm04.experimental-disk` beforehand)
5. start the VM again:

   ```
   xen create /etc/xen/vm04.experimental.cfg
   ```

Answer (score 2):

The proper format for `lvextend` is:

```
lvextend -L +40G /dev/vg0/vm04.experimental-disk
```

For instructions how to extend the partition in the VM itself use [this manual](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24027/how-can-i-resize-an-ext-root-partition-at-runtime).

> The partition must first be resized. If you're using LVM, it's easy,
>   and you presumably know how to proceed. If you're using classic
>   partitions, it's a bit more complicated, and may require a reboot
>   (though you never have to boot another system or live CD).
>
> This is how I do it: Use fdisk to first delete the partition (the idea
>   is that the data on disk will be preserved), then carefully recreate
>   it with a larger size at the same position.
>
> Again, it is critical that the new partition starts at the same block
>   as the old. The Id should also match (83 for Linux systems). Be
>   prepared to lose all your data at the slightest typo.
>
> To be on the safe side, you may also restore the boot flag (which
>   according to Wikipedia is still required on some computers) by
>   pressing a.
>
> See the comment section for what to do if your swap partition is in
>   the way.
>
> By now it should be apparent why people recommend using a live CD. ;-)
>   As fdisk helpfully reminds you, you must reload the partition table
>   before proceeding. The safest way is to simply reboot; but you can
>   also use partprobe or kpartx (more information).
>
> Once the partition is resized and the partition table reloaded, it's a
>   simple matter of running resize2fs on the file system, and you can do
>   this even when it's mounted as the root partition.

```
$ sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1
```

Comment: @rubo77, check my edited answer

Comment: note that if you're resizing an xfs disk rather than ext, use xfs_growfs instead of resize2fs.